# BASH - for loop not executing inside while loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

It was supposed to be a simple script but...anything that it's inside the for loop is not executing at all. If the IF statement is true, it checks the for statement "for pod in `oc get pods | grep -i '^pat*' | awk '{print $1}'`" and goes back at the beginning of the while loop infinitely . If the IF statement is false, it exists the script. In this case the if statement is always true, it should at list print the pod's name.After I redirect the stderr of the FOR statement to the console with 2> I get `"command substitution: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token`newline'"`, considering that the for loop contains only the echo command

```
while true; do
  check=$(curl --insecure https:...... | python -mjson.tool |head -2 |grep -i status|awk -F '"' '{print $4}')
  if [ $check == "OK" ]; then
    for pod in `oc get pods | grep -i '^pat*' | awk '{print $1}'`; do
      echo $pod
    done
  else
    exit 0
  fi 
done
```

The debug output looks like this:

```
+ true
++ python -mjson.tool
++ head -2
++ grep -i status
++ curl --insecure https:...
++ awk -F '"' '{print $4}'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   127  100   127    0     0    353      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   354

+ check=OK
+ '[' OK == OK ']'
++ grep -i '^pat*'
++ awk '{print $1}'
++ oc get pods
+ true
++ head -2
++ python -mjson.tool
++ awk -F '"' '{print $4}'
++ curl --insecure https:...
```

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time`  `Current`

```
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed



 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   127  100   127    0     0    415      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   416

+ check=OK
+ '[' OK == OK ']'
++ awk '{print $1}'
++ grep -i '^pat*'
++ oc get pods
+ true
++ python -mjson.tool
++ head -2
++ grep -i status
++ awk -F '"' '{print $4}'
++ curl --insecure https:...



 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   127  100   127    0     0    423      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   423
100   127  100   127    0     0    423      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   423

+ check=OK
+ '[' OK == OK ']'
++ grep -i '^pat*'
++ awk '{print $1}'
++ oc get pods
+ true
....
```

Comment: How does it "check" the `for` statement? Does it run it? What's the output? What should the output be?

Comment: It is supposed to kill a pod but at least print the pod name in this version, but it exists after it evaluates the for statement

Comment: Does `oc get pods` maybe print to stderr? You can check with `oc get pods 2> output` and see if `output` contains the output or if it goes to the console.

Comment: What part of that `set -x` trace reflects behavior other than what you intend? Once we know that, then we can start to focus in on the "why" -- but this code relies on a bunch of knowledge about expected behavior that right now only you have.

Comment: That said, note that `for item in $(...anything...)` -- for either that modern command substitution syntax or the legacy backtick one -- is bad form. See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I have an identical for loop in another script that is working without issues but it is in the main program not inside while loop and if statement like in this case but I think you were right, the output was printed to stderr and skipped the loop execution: "command substitution: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'",  considering that the for loop contains only the echo command and the line 31 is the echo

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the advices and documentation. I replaced my for loop with a while loop: while IFS= read -r line...but the result is the same as written in the comment above

Comment: @boncalomihai, that error message is critical information; include it in the question itself. BTW, I'd also suggest a `PS4` that includes line numbers so your `bash -x` log tells which line generated any given output. `PS4='${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO+'` is one I typically use. (If you're not running as root, you can use `PS4='...' bash -x yourscript` to set it through the environment; if you are, for security reasons some versions of bash won't honor that as an environment variable so you'll need to set it inside the script).

Comment: Within a `while read` loop, btw, it's helpful to log the values that have been read. So, say, `while IFS= read -r line; do : "line=$line"` will log each value of `line` right as the loop starts when you have xtrace logging turned on.

Comment: That said, your code snippet *includes* no line 31. Do make sure error messages line up with the code actually provided in the question, not the original code it's drawn from.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't knew about that error until BenjaminW. told me to output stderr to console.Thank you very much for your comments, I learned some useful stuff

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I should've edited the line number, this is only a part of the whole code.

Comment: Glad to hear your issue is solved! Do you think this can be distilled down to a FAQ entry that's helpful to other people with the same problem? (If not, you might consider deleting the question; this smells a bit like it falls into the "typographical error or problem that cannot be reproduced or is unlikely to help other people" category).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  , maybe someone will have the same error, same issue and if they see this topic, they will know what to look for in their code. Do you agree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more troubleshooting found that the issue was the grep `grep -i '^pat*'` from the FOR statement which wasn't returning any values thus skipping the execution. After replacing the pattern "^pat*" with the correct one, everything works